Decomposing complete graphs into edge-disjoint spanning trees
Given a complete graph with $N = 2k$ vertices, is it always possible to decompose it into $k$ edge disjoint spanning trees? If so, then is there a general procedure to find these trees? I would also be happy with the case where $N$ is a power of 2 instead of a multiple.
So far I've been able to do it for $N = 4, 6,$ and $8$. Obviously, the solution is not unique since if there exists a solution then any relabeling of the vertices will result in another solution.
For $N = 4$:
$\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)\}, \{(1,3),(1,4),(2,4)\}$
For $N = 6$:
$\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4), (4,5), (5,6)\}, \{(1,3),(1,5),(1,6), (4, 6), (2, 6)\}, \{(2,4), (1,4), (2,5), (3,5), (3,6)\}$
For $N = 8$:
$\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (6,7), (7,8)\}, \{(1,3),(3,5),(5,8), (2, 4), (4, 6), (4, 7), (5,7)\}, \{(1,5), (1,6), (2,6), (2,7), (3,7), (3,8), (4,8)\}, \{(1,4), (1,7), (1,8), (2,5), (2, 8), (3,6), (6,8)\}$

Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271763/how-to-find-two-disjoint-spanning-trees-of-an-undirected-graph will help

$K_{2k}$ can always be decomposed into $k$ Hamiltonian paths -- there's a systematic (but hard to describe) way to do it: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3697710/how-to-decompose-edges-of-k-n-into-hamiltonian-paths

Should an inductive construction work? Say we partitioned the complete graph on the vertex set $v_1, \dots, v_{2k}$ into a set of trees $T_1, \dots, T_k$. Now we add two new vertices $a, b$.
Let us introduce a new tree $T_{k+1}$ which consists of edges $(v_i, a)_{i=1}^k \cup (a,b) \cup (v_i, b)_{i=k+1}^{2k}$ and let's update each previous tree with two new edges: $T_i^\prime = T_i \cup (v_i, b) \cup (v_{k+i}, a)$. Then the set $T_1^\prime, \dots, T_k^\prime, T_{k+1}$ forms a new partition
